# How to convert a Sympy solution to a form that can be used with the uncertainties package? [Python]

Tags: python, sympy, python-packaging

I have the following task to accomplish:
[image]

As it is in german, here a quick translation:

I am expected to transform the given equation in a way that I then can fill in the given constants (and everything not given using `scipy.constants`) while using only `ufloats` from the "uncertainties" package. What I have so far is this:

```py
import  scipy.constants       as      sc
from    uncertainties         import  ufloat
import  uncertainties.umath   as      um
import  sympy                 as      sp

a, G, m, M, T =sp.symbols("a G m M T")

k3 = sp.Eq(T**2 / a**3 , 4*sp.pi**2/(G*(m+M)))

umlaufzeit = sp.solve(k3, T)[1]
```

so that the variable "umlaufzeit" (sorry that it is german...) holds the solution of the given equation for the positive expression of T. The only problem is that it is of the type "sympy.core.mul.Mul" which doesn't help me. I could cast it into a String using the `Str(umlaufzeit)` method, which gives it in the form `"2*pi*sqrt(a**3/(G*(M + m)))"`.

But then I still have the problem that I cannot use it the way I want, first it still is only a String, nothing I could do operations on, and second, in order to be able to calculate with the uncertainties package, I need to use only functions from the `uncertainties.math` package, e.g. "`um.sqrt(args)`" instead of the regular `sqrt(args)` from any other package.

**So in short:**

How do I convert the return value of `sympy.solve(<equation>, <parameter>)` into a form processable by the "uncertainties"-package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to convert the symbolic expression to a lambda function which can later be used for numerical evaluation. We can do that with the `lambdify` function (please, read its documentation).

Since you need to use the `uncertainties.umath` module for numerical evaluation, we also need to inform `lambdify` of this module. Here is how you do it:

```py
import uncertainties.umath   as      um
from sympy import *
a, G, m, M, T = symbols("a G m M T")
k3 = Eq(T**2 / a**3 , 4* pi**2/(G*(m+M)))
sol = solve(k3, T)[1]
f = lambdify([a, G, m, M], sol, modules=um)

# numerical values
_M = ufloat(1.990, 0.005) * 1e30
_m = ufloat(5.970, 0.005) * 1e24
_G = ufloat(6.6743, 0.00015) * 1e-11
_a = 149.6e09
# numerical evaluation
f(_a, _G, _m, _M)
# out: 31546211.244203605+/-39632.38513830719
```

Comment: Wow, that was very fast, thank you. I will definitely read the documentation of the lambdify function, this seems to solve the problem. Is the lambdify function integrated in the standard python or do I have to load it from a specific package in for it to work with the other packages?

Comment: It comes with SymPy.

Comment: @DarkDiamond thanks for letting me discover a new package (`uncertainties`). Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your problem :)

Comment: I will mark it as a solution, when I tested it. So far I did not find the time to try it.